# How do i make a JPassword Field launch an application

Tags: java, swing, passwords

```
JPanel p = new JPanel();              

JTextField userName = new JTextField(10);

JPasswordField passWord = new JPasswordField(10);                 

p.add(new JLabel("Username:"));
p.add(userName);
p.add(new JLabel("Password: "));
p.add(passWord);

JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, p, "Username and password: ", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
```

My question is how do i make it so The Username is username and the password is password and if you type in the correct username and password it launches the application if not it closes it?

Comment: what you want exactly. you want `JPasswordField` listener or something

Comment: i didn't understand with ur coment

Comment: @Dragon4c3_ don't you add a login button ? and what is your problem ?launching a exe ? or compare username and password ?

Comment: There are already 2 buttons ok and cancel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your gui,

```
int selectedOption = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, p, "Username and password: ", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION); 
if (selectedOption == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
if (userName.getText().equals("abc") && passWord.getText().equals("abc")) {
//do some action, login success
}
else
{
//do some action, login fail
}
}//end if
else
{
//do some action, means user cancel the login
}
```

Comment: Ok what do i do with the ... before ,JOptionPane??

Comment: Now I changed according to your need. @Dragon4c3_